# Returning a property of type List<>

Tags: c#, list, properties

I'm currently trying to return a match to a Foreach statement which is contained in a list.
I have a class that has a List of string, i'm using this as a collection of tracks.

I'm trying to perform a check to see if the given track i pass in through is a match to any tracks stored in the object (CD.cs) and if so return the entire CD's details.

I'm unsure as to how to so it, unfortunatly i've not used lists as much as i should do.

Here's a snippet of the Track Property: (Virtual as i'm overriding it in another class)

```
public virtual List<string> Track
    {
        get
        {
            return _track;
        }
        set
        {
            value = _track;
        }
    }
```

Here is the method i'm trying to use to return a match, quite easy to see where i'm going wrong i imagine.
:

```
public CD FindTrackInCD(string track)
{
        foreach (CD testCD in _cdCollection)
        {
            **//If given track matches any tracks in the list
            if (testCD.Track == track)
            {
                //Return the matching CD
                return trackInCD;
            }**
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("No matches found");
 }
```

The method i have in bold is the problem area, my compiler shows me this warning:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' and 'string'
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo but another problem you have is that your setter for Track is backward - it should set `_track = value` not `value = _track`

Comment: It's weird because i've not noticed it only as it seems to work still, i can't believe i've done it to be honest (too many late nights) but i'll fix it just in case, thanks =]

Comment: As a side note, it is generally not advised to have settable properties of collection types. The idea is that such collections should be owned solely by the object which exposes them via a property  - so it creates an instance in its constructor, and then the same instance is always returned by the getter. Clients can reasonably expect to obtain a reference to collection from such property, and assume that it will always refer to the "live" collection associated with that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
foreach (CD testCD in _cdCollection)
    {
        if (testCD.Track.Contains(track))
        {
            //Return the matching CD
            return testCD;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the code snippet, nudged me in the right direction.
It compiles fine and i'll begin testing right away.

Answer (score 1):

Rename it to `Tracks` and then you would use it `testCD.Tracks.Contains(track)`. Right now you are, as your error says, comparing a string and a list.